# Blazor Child Component EventCallBack not responding

Tags: c#, components, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Here Page Component

```
@page "/student"
<h3>Student List</h3>
<h5>@StudentsList</h5>

<StudentDetail StudentName="Something New" ButtonClicked="@Save"></StudentDetail>

<h5>This is second</h5>
<h5>@SaveMessage</h5>


@code {
    public string StudentsList { get; set; }
    private string SaveMessage { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        StudentsList = "ASD DSA KDS CFA";
    }

    private void Save(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveMessage = "Operation Saved.";
    }
}
```

And this is the StudentDetail

```
<h3>Student Detail for @StudentName</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onClick="ButtonClicked">Click Me!</button>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> ButtonClicked { get; set; }

}
```

I tried this on both Server and Client sides. When i click the "Click Me!" button, absolutely nothing happens. What am i doing wrong?

These are imports

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using BlazorApp4
@using BlazorApp4.Shared
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StudentDetail:

It's `@onclick`, not `@onClick` in `@onClick="ButtonClicked"`

When you click on the `"Click Me!"` button, you actually want to trigger the "Save" method in the Student component. This is how you do that:

```
`@onclick="() => ButtonClicked.InvokeAsync()"`
```

Student:
Change `ButtonClicked="@Save"` to `ButtonClicked="Save"`

Comment: Not works. Even try with calling async method like;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onClick="ExecuteAsync">Click Me!</button>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> ButtonClicked { get; set; }

    public async void ExecuteAsync(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        await ButtonClicked.InvokeAsync(e);
    }

}

still not works..

Comment: Once again: It's @onclick,

Comment: not @onClick. Do you see the difference. Don't use  async void, use  async Task